# When AngularJS triggers an $onEval, is there any way to immediately tell what values in this scope have changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to sync changes to the server automatically.  Currently I'm detecting changes in a **`scope.$onEval`** handler by JSON serializing the application state and comparing that to a previously serialized copy, using diff-match-patch.

I was wondering if AngularJS has anything built in to make this more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/angular.scope.%24watch)'es instead of a single `$onEval` (note that $watch can take a function as an argument instead of a string/expression, and in version >=0.10.0 the watched values are compared using [angular.Object.equals](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/angular.Object.equals)). Other than that, I don't know any AngularJS mechanism that would be useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something similar. Like @psyho suggested I am using [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/angular.scope.%24watch) to catch the changes.

```
scope.$watch("dataObject",function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //calculate changes
    //send the changes to the server
});
```

I then use the logic from [jquery diff](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/jquery-diff-11) to calculate what changes were made.